# Opposite of this if?

Tags: .net, reverse, if-statement

I have this "if" statement, but I'm really messed up today and can't think of how to reverse it to be better...

```
if (plist.Exists("No Update Ramdisk") && plist.Get<PlistBool>("No Update Ramdisk").Value)
{
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Just so you don't ask what plist is, I wrote a plist parser in .NET and I am scanning it for values

Comment: What is plist.Get<PlistBool>("No Update Ramdisk").Value ?
Is it boolean?

Comment: And what do you mean by "reverse it to be better"? It looks short now.

Comment: in what way do you want it 'better'?

Comment: yes
PlistBool.Value represents a boolean in a plist

Comment: reverse it so I dont have to do if(...){}else{...}, but if(...){...}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least three possibilities

- Swap THEN and ELSE Block
- Invert condition `if (! A)`
- Use De Morgan `(A && B) == !(!A || !B)`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 4):

To reverse*, `true` expressions should be `false`; and `and` operators should be `or`) :

```
if (!plist.Exists("No Update Ramdisk") 
    || !plist.Get<PlistBool>("No Update Ramdisk").Value)
{
    ...
}
```

<sub>*Assuming `Get<PlistBool>("No Update Ramdisk").Value` is a `bool`.</sub>